# Precessor and successor in Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I wanted to implement 2 codes, one for the biggest successor of x and one for the smallest predecessor of x in a binary tree.

```
data LookupTree a = Blatt  | Knoten a (LookupTree a) (LookupTree a)
biggestSucc :: Ord a => a -> LookupTree a -> Int
biggestSucc x Blatt = error "Am Knoten"
biggestSucc x (Knoten a l r)
    |a == x = max l r
    |a /= x = biggestSucc x _

smallestPre :: Ord a => a -> LookupTree a -> Int
smallestPre x Blatt = error "Am Knoten"
smallestPre x (Knoten a l r)
    |a == x = 
    |a /= x = smallestPre x _
```

The problem is the `max` and `min` function and the `smallestPre`/`biggestSucc x _` thing. But how else can I tell him to go on in both directions of the node? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you want to do something like check if a < x or if a > x and recurse down the left tree or right tree based on those checks?

Comment: What do you mean by successor and predecessor?

Comment: Give examples, what should it return for which input? Is the `LookupTree` contrained, e.g. left subtree should be smaller than the right? (Don't just answer *yes*, *smaller* is vague.)

Comment: These are binary _search_ trees, I guess? Otherwise, you need to fold over every node.

Comment: @SiXa are you stitll interested in this? The answer should be no big deal once you react to the points asked in the comments here - if not we should close the question

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the inorder predecessor or successor of a node in a BST, then I am presenting the solution below. I don't understand what you mean by the smallest predecessor of a node because the smallest predecessor of a node is just the smallest element in the BST which is extremely easy to find.

So what I am demonstrating below is given a Node finding the inorder predecessor or the largest predecessor:

The signature which you give will not work because we need to encode the parent information:

Hence the tree will look like this:

```
type Parent = BstP
type LChild = BstP
type RChild = BstP

data BstP = None | Node1 Key Parent LChild RChild deriving Show
```

And the code to find the inorder predecessor is given below:

```
type Key = Int

predecessor :: BstP -> Key
predecessor  None              = undefined
predecessor (Node1 a p None _) = findPredAncestor a p
predecessor (Node1 a _ l _)    = treeMaximumP l

treeMaximumP :: BstP -> Key
treeMaximumP  None               = undefined
treeMaximumP (Node1 a _ _ None ) = a
treeMaximumP (Node1 _ _ _ r)     = treeMaximumP r

findPredAncestor :: Key -> BstP -> Key
findPredAncestor k (Node1 a p l r)
  | (keyP r) == k = a
  | otherwise = findPredAncestor a p

keyP :: BstP -> Key
keyP  None           = undefined
keyP (Node1 a _ _ _) = a
```